# How to add Flutter Firebase VIdeo Upload Progrese Indecator | Upload Progress Indicator |

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

How to add Flutter Firebase VIdeo Upload Progrese Indecator | Upload Progress Indicator |
Anyone can help me

```
MediaInfo compressVideo = await VideoCompress.compressVideo(
  videoPath,
  quality: VideoQuality.Res640x480Quality,
  includeAudio: true,
);
print('video Compressing Done');

var uploadVideo = await FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child("videos/${Me.get().uid}/${videoDoc.id}")
    .putFile(File(compressVideo?.path));
print('video Uploading Done');

final videoUrl = await uploadVideo.ref.getDownloadURL();
showToast("Upload Successful");
```

Answer (score 2):

This should be a good example from it:

```
Future<void> handleTaskExample2(String filePath) async {
  File largeFile = File(filePath);

  firebase_storage.UploadTask task = firebase_storage.FirebaseStorage.instance
      .ref("videos/${Me.get().uid}/${videoDoc.id}")
      .putFile(File(compressVideo?.path));

  task.snapshotEvents.listen((firebase_storage.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {
    print('Task state: ${snapshot.state}');
    print(
        'Progress: ${(snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) * 100} %');
  }, onError: (e) {
    // The final snapshot is also available on the task via `.snapshot`,
    // this can include 2 additional states, `TaskState.error` & `TaskState.canceled`
    print(task.snapshot);

    if (e.code == 'permission-denied') {
      print('User does not have permission to upload to this reference.');
    }
  });

  // We can still optionally use the Future alongside the stream.
  try {
    await task;
    print('Upload complete.');
  } on firebase_core.FirebaseException catch (e) {
    if (e.code == 'permission-denied') {
      print('User does not have permission to upload to this reference.');
    }
    // ...
  }
}
```

I would also recommend to check the [docs](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/storage/usage#handling-tasks) for more details.

Comment: I have been already tried this. It's not working in my case

Answer (score 0):

finally, I'm getting the right answer.
This answer is perfectly works in my case.

```
//This is the document reference 
Reference videoRef = FirebaseStorage.instance
    .ref()
    .child("videos/${Me.get().uid}/${videoDoc.id}");

//Here video is uploading and return UploadTask
UploadTask videoTask = videoRef.putFile(compressVideo.file);

//This is upload task StreamSubscription
final StreamSubscription<void> streamSubscription =
    videoTask.snapshotEvents.listen((data) {
  double uploadPer;
  setState(() => uploadPer = (data.bytesTransferred / data.totalBytes)* 
 100);
print(uploadPer); 
});

//When video uploading is completed then streamSubscription is cancel.
await videoTask.whenComplete(() => null);
streamSubscription.cancel();

//This is finally get video download URL 
final String videoUrl = await videoRef.getDownloadURL();
print(videoUrl);
showToast("Upload Successful");
```